# Get SQL commandtext and parameters from EntityFramework ObjectQuery

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, objectquery

I have some queries that EF is unable to support: spatial, indexhints, etc. etc.
Most of the data however is EF friendly and I can use the linq provider.

Example:
I have  Person, PersonAddress and Address tables. On Address I have a spatial index that must be used to define an area for the search. Based on that I want to filter further e.g. on Person.BirthDate.
I already have this implemented in T-SQL, but only with fixed parameters.

Instead I want to combine the spatial, and the entity framework queries, and to do that I need to get the SQL command text and parameters from an ObjectQuery.
When I have those combinding these will be easy. Unfortunately I can only get the command text using ObjectQuery.ToTraceString().

I'm using linqpad, and I see that it is able to get both parameters and text, so this must be possible.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinqPad is the most probably using something similar to all tracing and profiling tools. Check [tracing wrapper](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) for the sample. It is just wrapper for a provider generating SQL queries but on a wrapper level you have absolutely no knowledge about type of executed query. It is just `DbCommand`. The only way to modify SQL when you have context of executed linq query is in [custom provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/05/writing-an-ef-enabled-ado-net-provider.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tracing wrapper example. This has all the missing pieces. All I have to do now is to implement a custom Ado.net provider. After all I'm not interested in a wrapped connection, only in a 100% disconnected.